# Invite facebook friends with multi friend selector

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-requests

To invite friends in facebook I used following code

```
            FB.init({
               appId:'APP_ID',
               cookie:true,
               status:true,
               xfbml:true
             });

            function FacebookInviteFriends()
              {
                 FB.ui({
                 method: 'apprequests',
                 message: 'Your Message diaolog'
                  });
              }
```

Its giving as shown below[image: see here]

But what I need is
[click here to see](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kcaAH.png)

How can I get it.

Answer (score 0):

```
FB.ui({
   method: 'apprequests',
   message: 'Your Message diaolog',
   to: 'uid1,uid2'
});
```